# MySQL loop and multiple LEFT joins

Tags: mysql

I got the following code:

```
SELECT 
      COALESCE(rv.views, 0) as views
   FROM 
      ( select 0 as n 
        union all select 1 
        union all select 2 
        union all select 3 ) n 
        LEFT JOIN restaurant_views rv 
           on rv.date = date_add("2015-02-24", interval - n.n day) 
           and restaurant_id = 192
```

[image]

This code is giving me the amount of views a restaurant had the last 4 days.
I am looking for a similar query to get the amount of *likes* a restaurant had the last 4 days.

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT 
      ( COUNT( DISTINCT a.restaurant_id) 
      + COUNT( DISTINCT d.restaurant_id)) as num_likes
   FROM 
      ( select 0 as n 
        union all select 1 
        union all select 2 
        union all select 3 ) n 
         LEFT JOIN apple_likes a 
            on a.vote_date = date_add("2015-02-24", interval - n.n day) 
            and a.restaurant_id = 192
         LEFT JOIN android_likes d 
            on d.vote_date = date_add("2015-02-24", interval - n.n day) 
            and d.restaurant_id = 192
```

And here is the output, which is as you can see not what I'm looking for:
[image]

What do I have to change to get the number of likes in the last query?
*(I have checked that the restaurant has likes on all days, so I am positive it's something wrong with the query)*

Comment: Correct me if I got it wrong please. The difference between old query that works and new one you want to get is that `rv.views` holds the ready to use counter data? but  `apple_likes` and `android_likes` doesn't and you need to count it using query functions?

Comment: Can you post some sample data so that we can try and recreate this issue?

Comment: @Alex, that is a possibility. Can you show an example?

Comment: @Alex Yes, you are totally right, my bad! What I meant by my last comment was if you could show me an example of how I could count the **num_likes** before the date-calculations are starting. Again sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
      ( a.likes) 
      + d.likes) as num_likes
   FROM 
      ( select 0 as n 
        union all select 1 
        union all select 2 
        union all select 3 ) n 
         LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT vote_date,COUNT(*) as likes 
            FROM apple_likes
            WHERE restaurant_id = 192
            GROUP BY restaurant_id, vote_date
         ) as a 
            on a.vote_date = date_add("2015-02-24", interval - n.n day) 
         LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT vote_date, COUNT(*) as likes 
            FROM android_likes 
            WHERE restaurant_id = 192
            GROUP BY restaurant_id, vote_date
         ) as d 
            on d.vote_date = date_add("2015-02-24", interval - n.n day)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the input! I tried it, and I also tried this: *SELECT a.likes, d.likes, a.vote_date, d.vote_date*, but all fields are NULL sadly.

Comment: so does it work for you?if it doesn't I need `apple_likes` table structure and  `android_likes` table structure and samples of data there

Comment: It works, but returns NULL for all fields. I tried to SELECT * and everything is NULL. All the table names and columns are correct. Updating the question in 1 min with structures

Comment: does it return 4 rows?

Comment: Yep! All 4 rows gets returned

Comment: are you sure that there are records with date equal `2015-02-24`, `2015-02-23`,`2015-02-22` etc ???

Comment: That was it!!!! **DATE(vote_date)** solved it since vote_date is a datetime!  I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple items that might be what you are encountering...

1. Just because somebody VIEWS a restaurant, does that mean they actually VOTED???  And if Voted, are the only two devices that of apple or android?  What if viewing from a browser and they are on a Windows machine browser-based?
2. Date Equality.  In the restaurant views table, is the date field ALWAYS that of a time = 12:00:00 (ie: midnight/morning of the day).  If the time-stamps of the votes are anything other than 12:00:00, and you are trying to compare for a date = date + time is probably failing.  What you may need is a comparison of the date( vote_date ) = date( date_add( ... )) so this way BOTH are ignoring the time component...  Now, that being said, a function on a date column is not going to be optimized, even if the restaurant ID is numeric and part of the index key... it would be PARTIALLY optimized.  You may want to just add a generic date of AND vote_date >= '2015-02-20' so it can optimize the restaurant and date, then apply the DATE( vote_date ) for the actual qualfying of records.

Comment: 1. Nope, the views and votes (likes) are totally different, a like is when they click 'Like' on the restaurant. A view is only when they see the restaurant in the app.

Comment: 2. The date is OK. If I add 00:00 it would still act the same.

Comment: @Tompa, then is it possible that there are no VOTE records for the restaurant in question?  Have you tried manually by explicitly putting in a date range such as > '2015-02-20' just to confirm activity?